# Ajax autocomplete on input with already some events associated

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small project where i did a table excel-like. Each table cell contains a disabled input, and when you click any cell that input becomes enabled so you can type, changes the color of that cell+the entire row, and you can switch to next row using TAB, or next line using ENTER, or UP and DOWN for the cell above or below it. When the row is changed it will call an ajax function to update the data to the database.

That was the project description so far. My problem is:

I need to have auto-complete on some columns of the table. I tried so far Bootstrap typeahead, JqueryUI autocomplete and a couple of others more. None of them seem to work for my case. The main reason is that they overwrite my events.

I tried to add the autocomplete function on one specific cell only, to test how it works. And that cell won't become enable when i click it because my javascript is disabled by that autocomplete.

I tried to enable it from code to see how it works, and indeed the autocomplete seem to show up, but then my UP and DOWN arrowkeys are messed up.

Any idea on how to get an autocomplete to work on this case?

Thank you, any idea is much appreciated, I've been brainstorming on this for 2 days.

Comment: After a few more atempts, i tried to add a single onchange event on an input and it also fails. This seems to be the problem of autocomplete.

Comment: show code or it's not a real S.O question.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very simple script that can do the Job... http://dev.twiip.ch/scripts/autocomplete/

they link provide an easy example to select some data from a mysql database using php and ajax.

it is in french, you can use google translate to understand.